# Remove items from a list of tuples based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, loops, tuples, conditional-statements

I have a list of tuples of different sizes. I want to iterate over each tuple and remove value from the tuple if the previous value is three digit number.

For example:

```
ls = [(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (222, 234, 250, 10), ...]
```

I need to get a list in that form:

```
ls1 = [(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (222, 234, 250), ...]
```

Comment: Why doesn't the third `tuple` in your output break after `222`? And what is the rule if the tuple starts with 4 digit number?

Comment: your tuples should really be lists if you need to remove elements from them.

Comment: It is just an example, my tuples are around 2000 long, so it is just demonstration to get an idea want I want to get.

Comment: what about `[(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (222, 234, 250, 10, 111, 222), ...]` ?

Comment: Typically, 2 digits number (for example 10 as in my example) at the end of each tuple and three digits number before that 10. So I need to remove that 10 from tuples if before that 10 is three digits number.

Comment: I tried list comprehension like that [x[:-1] if x[-1] == 10 and len(str(x[-2])) == 3 else x for x in  ls] but it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simple loop with if-else condition will do the work

```py
ls = [(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (222, 234, 250, 10)]

three_digit_seen = False

output = []

for i in ls:
    three_digit_seen = False
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        if(len(str(j)) == 3):
            three_digit_seen = True
        if(three_digit_seen and (len(str(j)) != 3)):
            continue
        temp.append(j)
            
    output.append(tuple(temp.copy()))
    
print(output)
```

```
[(1, 1, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (222, 234, 250)]
```